# Debug C++ in VS2017 on WSL - unknown arch error

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2017, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a c++ linux project in vs2017.
I setup a connection to WSL (windows sub system for linux).
When I build or try to debug I get the following error:

`Current project architecture ‘x64’ is incompatible with the remote system architecture ” (‘Unknown’). Please switch the project architecture to ” in Configuration Manager`

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's an artifact of a bad ssh connection. 
I think that it tries to connect to the windows ssh server, which hijacks connection instead of forwarding to WSL.

First I changed the connection port in visual studio (Tools -> Options -> Cross Platform -> Connection Manager) from the default 22 to 222.

In addition, I found the following steps helpful on the WSL side (taken from https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/5gh4c8/ssh_to_bash_on_wsl/):

- Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change the listening port. For this demo I used port 222.
- Change UsePrivilegeSeparation to 'no' (because the implementation of the Windows subsystem for Linux doesn't provide chroot)
- Change PasswordAuthentication to 'yes'
- Add a firewall rule on the Windows side for SSH to your new listening port
- sudo ssh-keygen -A
- Restart the ssh service: sudo service ssh --full-restart
- Test ssh connection locally with verbose mode enabled (verbose mode optional): ssh localhost -p "your-port-here" -v
- Test from another system. (All should be working)

Comment: You should use port 2222 as port 222 is under 1024 and tho reserved. In fact, in the [reserved port list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), there's no application using it, but it's a good practice.